# How do we treat very individual routine questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This is a question, that sort of bugs me, and I have voted to close, but would be interested in other opinions.
[Increasing Weight : Plateau stage](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13298/increasing-weight-plateau-stage)

In essense this is a shopping question - "my routine is not working for me, what can I do to meet my goals?" Its unlikely that someone is going to come along with the exact same weight/height/sex/routine, so there is no easy way to answer this question that would be helpful for someone in the future.

In my hast I flagged this question as "unclear what you're asking", but have since found a better duplicate (but can't retract my vote) - [Pushing past a weight plateau?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/549/pushing-past-a-weight-plateau/553#553)

**Is it possible to have a close vote option that helps explain that the question is "too specific to the asker and unlikely to be applicable to a wider audience"?**

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is a good question (this on meta, no comment on the post being discussed). I'd say that if there's another question on a very similar routine, we could consider it a duplicate, but most people are following some routine they read about and there's a lot of value to allowing some of these to be analyzed.

Comment: I don't have a "too localised" option. That was the one that I was thinking of, but it disappeared.

Comment: You're right! When did that change? :-)

Comment: I don't know. But I miss it :(

Comment: @Greg [It's on the network meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/176874) check bullet point 5(A)